# Trying to connect to AzureAD with PowerShell but getting unknow credential

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, powershell-az-module

I can connect to AzureAD using the following command just fine and run queries against AD

```
Connect-AzureAD -Confirm
```

However when i attempt to user the Get-Credential and store it as a variable, it does not seem to work, not sure why i am getting the Unsupported User Type 'Unkown'

```
> $Credential = Get-Credential

cmdlet Get-Credential at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Credential
> Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential
WARNING: Install the latest PowerShell module, the Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK, for new features and improvements!
https://aka.ms/graphPSmigration
Connect-AzureAD : One or more errors occurred.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : AuthenticationError: (:) [Connect-AzureAD], AggregateException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Connect-AzureAD,Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.ConnectAzureAD

Connect-AzureAD : Unsupported User Type 'Unknown'. Please see https://aka.ms/msal-net-up.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : AuthenticationError: (:) [Connect-AzureAD], MsalClientException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Connect-AzureAD,Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.ConnectAzureAD

Connect-AzureAD : One or more errors occurred.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-AzureAD], AggregateException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.AggregateException,Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.ConnectAzureAD
```

I know my creds are right when storing them as the variable, not sure why i get an error when using this method.
[image]

Comment: You are trying to make a connection between the local machine and a remote machine.  The remote machine is not recognizing the local credentials.   Are the two machine in the same domain?  Are the machines using Windows Credentials or OAUTH2?

Comment: The two machines are on the same domain, i am using smart card credentials as well.

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to connect to AzureAD with PowerShell but getting unknow credential.

Thanks to `jdweng` for suggesting the same point.

The above error is encountered when you are passing local `VM` credentials for connecting to `Azure AD`. Azure AD requires the user **UPN**  and **password**, as it needs the domain name for connecting to `Azure AD`.

[image]

When I pass the correct `Azure AD UPN` and `password` instead of a local username, it connects to `Azure AD` and is able to fetch the user details.

```
    Install-Module AzureAD
    $Credential = Get-Credential
    Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential
    Get-AzureADUser -Top 10
```

[image]

Comment: so our company uses smart cards for our user accounts, are you saying that i can not use my local windows account with Get-Credential ? I need an Azure AD account? Was following this article for ref: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powershell-support-for-certificate-credentials/

Comment: @BLang : OP is referring to UPN (User Principal Name) which includes the Domain.  See : https://www.codetwo.com/kb/upn/  Try using whoami to get the users and domain name.

Comment: I know its my lack of understanding with windows machines and AD, but im still confused, why is that Connect-AzureAD -Confirm (input into gui) lets me auth successfully, but then when i put the same credentials in the Get-Credentials (follow the same gui with my UN/PIN) it does not work? And the whoami on my machine matches my tenantDomain

Comment: If the machine is joined to the same Azure AD domain and logged in with the same user, you can log in with the same user by passing the domain name. It won't accept a PIN; the PIN is only on the device itself, not in Azure AD. For example: venkat@sample.com.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by Venkat V, the issue is probably due to how you are passing the user login information. As long as you provide the UPN the command will work, but you should also take into consideration that by getting credentials and using -credential you are performing basic auth which will be a problem in some cases, specially  if you have MFA configured.

As a simple solution, since you are using Get-Credential to get username and password, you can just directly call the Connect-AzureAD and that will prompt through normal Azure login screen for the user to type his credentials for authentication.

On a side note, you should avoid using the AzureAD module and instead use the Microsoft Graph Powershell module. The AzureAD module is already schedule for deprecation.